# Reference request: Finite difference methods on curvilinear (body fitted) grids

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I was wondering if someone may be aware of some form of detailed summary (book, tutorial paper) about the use of finite difference methods on curvilinear (body fitted) grids.

I was only able to locate some lecture slides on the transformation of the PDE (http://www3.nd.edu/~gtryggva/CFD-Course/2013-Lecture-23.pdf) but what I am looking for is practical information on the application details of the theory using the finite difference method.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Please check chapter 6 in the [bible for computational fluid dynamics](http://books.google.com/books?id=dJceAQAAIAAJ) by Anderson.

I believe many books in computational fluid dynamics afterwards discussed this topic as well. I have the book by Ferziger and Peric, it addresses the problem on body-fitted grids as well. The program in which can be downloaded [here](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/technik/peric) on Springer's ftp site, codes are in Fortran 77 and use finite volume method to solve equation, which can be adapted to finite difference for it is using rectangular grids.

I read through the slides you gave briefly, IMHO it does a good job in explaining the body fitted grids, essentially what it does is changing of variables. Once you get the equation for $\xi$ and $\eta$:
$$
\nabla^2 f =\frac{1}{J} (q_1 f_{\xi\xi}− 2q_2 f_{\eta\xi} +q_3 f_{\eta\eta}) + (\nabla^2\xi)f_{\xi}+ (\nabla^2\eta)f_{\eta},
$$
just apply the unsual finite difference discretization in $\xi-\eta$ coordinate system.

Some recent advances are mimetic finite difference method, please see [here](http://cnls.lanl.gov/~shashkov/papers/maxjcp.pdf) and [here](http://math.lanl.gov/~lipnikov/Slides/july_BLSSi05.pdf). It preserves the geometrical meaning of the differential operator, and deals with the unstructured grids problem in the slides you gave.